# Android Development: How to make a custom status bar Notification?

Tags: android, statusbar

I've tried and tried today just to get a custom message with 2 buttons and a TextView.
Ive got the XML alraight. But the code i tried to use just give me Force Close

```
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
        contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.Button01, R.drawable.icon);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.Button01, "Hello, this message is in a custom expanded view");

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, main.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
```

and im pretty lost so please dont send me to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html
Ive tried.

Would be really happy if someone could show me from the beggining because i have litterly tried this all the day and would really really appreciate a good answer!

Thank you!

//Lukas

EDIT* FULL CODE TO VIKTOR

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);

        int icon = R.drawable.icon;
        CharSequence tickerText = "Hello";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;


        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
        contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.Button01, R.drawable.icon);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.Button01, "Hello, this message is in a custom expanded view");


        notification.contentView = contentView;

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, main.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
        final int CUSTOM_VIEW_ID = 1;
        mNotificationManager.notify(CUSTOM_VIEW_ID, notification);

    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337): couldn't inflate view for notification Com.haxxzor.multitask/0x1
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.HorizontalScrollView
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337):     at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:939)
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337):     at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarService.makeNotificationView(StatusBarService.java:524)
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337):     at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarService.addNotificationViews(StatusBarService.java:553)
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337):     at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarService.addNotification(StatusBarService.java:382)
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337):     at com.android.systemui.statusbar.CommandQueue$H.handleMessage(CommandQueue.java:178)
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Class not allowed to be inflated android.widget.HorizontalScrollView
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.failNotAllowed(LayoutInflater.java:530)
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:477)
04-27 14:43:07.035: ERROR/StatusBarService(337):     ... 17 more
04-27 14:43:10.113: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(815): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 14:43:10.113: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(815): android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package Com.haxxzor.multitask: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(package=Com.haxxzor.multitask id=1 tag=null notification=Notification(vibrate=null,sound=null,defaults=0x0,flags=0x2))
04-27 14:43:10.113: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(815):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1044)
04-27 14:43:10.113: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(815):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-27 14:43:10.113: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(815):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-27 14:43:10.113: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(815):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-27 14:43:10.113: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(815):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 14:43:10.113: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(815):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-27 14:43:10.113: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(815):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-27 14:43:10.113: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(815):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-27 14:43:10.113: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(815):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-27 14:47:12.065: ERROR/InputDispatcher(44): channel '40643090 com.notif/com.notif.main (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
04-27 14:47:12.065: ERROR/InputDispatcher(44): channel '40643090 com.notif/com.notif.main (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-27 14:47:31.551: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(885): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 14:47:31.551: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(885): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.notif/com.notif.main}: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify()
04-27 14:47:31.551: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(885):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-27 14:47:31.551: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(885):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-27 14:47:31.551: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(885):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-27 14:47:31.551: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(885):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-27 14:47:31.551: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(885):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-27 14:47:31.551: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(885):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-27 14:47:31.551: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(885):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-27 14:47:31.551: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(885):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 14:47:31.551: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(885):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-27 14:47:31.551: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(885):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-27 14:47:31.551: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(885):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-27 14:47:31.551: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(885):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-27 14:47:31.551: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(885): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify()
04-27 14:47:31.551: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(885):     at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
04-27 14:47:31.551: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(885):     at com.notif.main.onCreate(main.java:27)
04-27 14:47:31.551: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(885):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-27 14:47:31.551: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(885):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-27 14:47:31.551: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(885):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you're actually notifying the user? And are you assigning the `contentView` to your `Notification` object's `contentView`?

Comment: You should post the exception that is causing the crash.

Comment: @Viktor Lannér Sorry as i said im lost sorry. I've deleted most of it becuase it didn't work. But if you can help me i would be very happy!

Comment: @carefacerz: Can you post the full code that did not work in an edit of your question?

Comment: @hackbod I don't have any catch. Don't know how to do it neither. But if you know how to make a custom notification please answer :)

Comment: If you learn to use LogCat, it will show you the exact line the error occurs on. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/index.html

Comment: @carefacerz: Can you also locate which line of that piece of code that doesn't work in LogCat?

Comment: @Blundell I have logcat showed but it's just like greek

Comment: @carefacerz yeah it takes time, you gotta ignore all the crap that's not to do with you. Look for where it says EXCEPTION and then look for your package name like com.blundell.package. This will then show you one of your class names and a line number

Comment: Try this video, extreme help.
http://youtu.be/e74z0_Z5QWI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have posted the error message, this line tells you why you're not succeeding with the custom notification:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Class not allowed to be inflated android.widget.HorizontalScrollView

Remove the `HorizontalScrollView` and just test with simple `TextView`s / `ImageView`s.

Comment: Can you post the LogCat message? Red marked text will tell you where the error was detected.

Comment: @carefacerz: Mark the line and paste it in an edited version of your question.

Comment: When i copy, the text just getting in a big mess.

Comment: Well, post that "big mess". :-)